# Searching for a linear operator specified as a recurrent relation

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I am learning about operators and some other stuff in linear algebra, and I have never encountered a problem that involves a linear operator which is defined recursively, that is:

$$A: V \to V$$

$$A = \begin{cases}
f(A(...)) \text{ in general} \\
\text{<constant>}  \text{ if <boundary case>}
\end{cases}$$

Matrix determinant is close (if you define it recursively as a sum of products), but $\det \mu A \ne \mu \det A$, so it's not a linear operator. Unless, perhaps, the matrix is populated by members of $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0, 1\}$.

Do you know about any interesting linear maps between vector spaces which are defined as recurrent relations?

Answer (score 1):

There is, for example, a recursion for these matrices here:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^n
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_{n} & F_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix},$$

where the Fibonacci numbers are recursively defined by

$$\begin{eqnarray}
F_0&=&0\\
F_1&=&1\\
F_{n+1}&=&F_n+F_{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Interestingly, If you have an $(m \times m)$ matrix like $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & ... \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{pmatrix}$, Then $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_n & F_n & ...\\ F_n & F_{n-1} & F_{n-1} & ... \\ F_n & F_{n-1} & F_{n-1} & ... \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{pmatrix} $ where $F_0 = 0$,  $F_1 = 1$ and $F_n = (m-1)F_{n-2} + F_{n-1}$.

Comment: Still, I don't understand how I can turn this into a linear operator.

Comment: We have the linear operator $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. It satisfies the recursion $A^{n-1} +A^n=A^{n+1}$.